# Ignore linebreaks in Strings

Tags: perl, line-breaks

Is it possible to tell Perl to ignore linebreaks in Strings?

I need linebreaks for formatting reasons as I have very long strings.

E.g.

```
print "hello 
world"
```

shall give

```
hello world
```

and not

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 4):

Concatenate your strings

```
print "hello"
    . "world";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple strings to [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) instead of one big one:

```
print "hello", "world";
```

Assuming of course that you haven't been messing around with [`$,`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2c) and that you're really using `print`.

Comment: Oh, that's more sensible than concatenation =)  It's been years since I wrote any Perl!

Comment: @paddy: But it only works if you're printing, `.` is they way to go if you're doing things like `my $s = "hello" . "world";`.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using concatenation**

> print "hello ". 
>       "world";

**2. By sending multiple arguments to print function**

> print ("hello ", "world");

Try it on [codepad](http://codepad.org/CkcO3w8j).